# Command not found via shell script but works on terminal

Tags: bash, shell

In my shell script I cannot invoke `ant`, or `mv` or `cp` commands,
but the same commands execute on terminal. Below is my script:

sample.sh file

```
#! /bin/sh
cp filename.so filename_org.so
android update project -p .
ant clean
ant release
```

PATH is set in the `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/
```

`cp`, `mv`, `ant` are working only under terminal not via script.

Comment: Give us more info about yur problem..

Comment: `android` / `ant`, are these binaries in /usr/bin?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As your script is a shell script (`/bin/sh`), then your `PATH` entries in `.bashrc` will not be read as that is for the `bash` (`/bin/bash`) interactive shell.

To make your `PATH` entries available to `/bin/sh` scripts run by a specific user, add the `PATH` entry to the `.profile` file in that users home directory.

---

Additionally you could add the full path for each of your commands within the script:

```
/bin/cp filename.so filename_org.so
```

Or set the `PATH` variable including all the required `$PATHS` at the beginning of your script.

```
PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin:xxx
export PATH
```

Comment: Correct analysis, but you didn't mention the right solution, which is to set `PATH` in the proper place instead of `.bashrc`. Changing the script to be a bash script will not make any difference: `.bashrc` is only loaded by interactive shells.

Comment: Just a tip for people getting this behavior trying to run a shell script via docker, and it works if you just run a shell and attach using `-ti`, typing the command manually, but not when you specify it as the command: you might be mapping a volume using `-v` onto your container in a way that wipes out the path to what you were trying to run.

Comment: "which is to set PATH in the proper place".....it might be more correct to `source ~/.bash_rc` in the script rather than setting the path directly. Any solution is a trade off.

Answer (score 4):

you can do one simple thing if you have small script and finish your work asap

go on command line use below command

```
which your_command
```

above command will print output including path use that command direct

Comment: `which` is a nonstandard utility; whether it tells the actual truth, or even exists at all, is system-dependent. POSIX specifies `type` and `command -v` as portable replacements.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue while running a binary whose path is set in bashrc.

Solved the issue by doing the following:

Add the binary or add a link to the binary in /usr/bin.

```
ln -s [path_to_binary] [name_of_executable]
```

Then check using

```
ls -l
```

You can remove the entry form bashrc.